# Are the dead maggots in a wound dangerous to the dog?

Tags: dogs, health, medicines

I have 2 month old German Shepherd puppy which had a wound on her head and maggots inside her wound. I have consulted with a vet and they treated her with injection and a spray.

She is fine now and the living insects are dead inside wound. They are black in colour now and the dog is playing and feeding well.

Are those dead insects inside wound dangerous to the dog or not?

Comment: Please call your vet and ask them this question. If and when your dog need more help, they will be better able to do so then we.